# Push Notification Automation using Appium

Tags: android, push-notification, automation, automated-tests, appium

How to automate test case to assert when push notification is received on android using appium automation?

I want to automate the test case when push notification is received.
How to check if push notification is received?
How to check if the push notification is from my app (package) ?
How to assert that this push notification is mine and received successfully?

Comment: What did you tried so far? Please edit your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below code to get all notification titles and then iterate it.

```
    driver.openNotifications();

    List<WebElement> allnotifications=driver.findElements(By.id("android:id/title"));

    for (WebElement webElement : allnotifications) {
        System.out.println(webElement.getText());
        if(webElement.getText().contains("something")){
            System.out.println("Notification found");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @SunShine no ! please check tags for iOS notifications and use it.

Comment: @ShekharSwami, can you please provide more insight? How to check iOS tags? Your help is greatly appreciated, I am pretty new to this.